# Drupal + SOLR Indexing -- Fields not showing up in "Enabled Filters" Tab

Tags: apache, drupal-6, solr, indexing

After doing an import of a content type (fairly large), the Apache SOLR admin page is not displaying that new content type's fields in the "Enabled Filters" Tab. I have already successfully done this in 4 other server environments, but this time, a half hour after importing the content type, I am still not seeing the fields.

The location of this menu is:

admin > Site Configuration > Apache SOLR > Enabled Filters

I have tried deleting and reimporting this content type, with no change in results. I have also (briefly) encountered this problem on 1 server prior to this, although after refreshing this tab a few times, all the fields magically appeared.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I might get these new fields to display as options in SOLR's config menu under the "Enabled Filters" tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, SOLR does not, by default, index numeric fields. However, we wrote a plugin for this, which I forgot to enable on this server. Thus, several fields were not showing up in the  enable filters page. It's always the little oversights that cause you the most trouble.

Answer (score 1):

you need to index content. Actually it's indexing automatically via cron, but since it can be not configured on server, you have to do it manually.

Comment: When you say index content, are you talking about to get search results from SOLR? Because I'm not talking about searching SOLR for nodes. I'm talking about configuring SOLR in the admistration menu. In the SOLR menu, under the "Enabled Filters" tab, there is a checkbox list of cck fields you can check to have indexed as filters that will be returned when you eventually do a SOLR search on the indexed content. The fields from my new content type are not showing up in that list, as they have on my countless other deployments to different servers.

Comment: under "enabled filters" you just enable the filters, not index content. So even if you enable one filter here and did not index content, filter remains empty.
usually indexing runs on cron tasks. 
after node update / new field / content type being added, nodes won't get indexed immediately, they set to index queue, and then, after cron run or manual run, your new fields as well as content types goes to SOLR.
So, go to search index, press reindex all content and run cron. And then make sure that at admin/settings/search, 100% of content being indexed.

This might help.

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, everyone seems to make the assumption that I'm having trouble indexing content. I'm not. The fields I want to enable as filters were not showing up in the enable filters tab.